# Tiny mce editor doesn't work on https url

Tags: javascript, laravel, tinymce

I have test website (developing site) works on http and my editor loads without any issue but since i moved my app to main site which runs on https my editor stopped loading and I get this error in console:

> ReferenceError: tinymce is not defined

## Screenshots

`http site`

[image: one]

`https site`

[image: two]

## Code

`JavaScript`

```
<script>
  var editor_config = {
    path_absolute : "/",
    selector: "textarea.editor",  //get class name "editor"
    plugins: [
      "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
      "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
      "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
      "emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern codesample",
      "fullpage toc tinymcespellchecker imagetools help"
    ],
    toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic strikethrough | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | ltr rtl | bullist numlist outdent indent removeformat formatselect| link image media | emoticons charmap | code codesample | forecolor backcolor",
    external_plugins: { "nanospell": "https://www.mysiteurl.com/js/tinymce/plugins/nanospell/plugin.js" },
    nanospell_server:"php",
    browser_spellcheck: true,
    relative_urls: true,
    remove_script_host: false,
    branding: false,
    file_browser_callback : function(field_name, url, type, win) {
      var x = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth;
      var y = window.innerHeight|| document.documentElement.clientHeight|| document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientHeight;

      var cmsURL = editor_config.path_absolute + 'laravel-filemanager?field_name=' + field_name;
      if (type == 'image') {
        cmsURL = cmsURL + "&type=Images";
      } else {
        cmsURL = cmsURL + "&type=Files";
      }

      tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
        file: '<?= route('elfinder.tinymce4') ?>',// use an absolute path!
        title: 'File manager',
        width: 900,
        height: 450,
        resizable: 'yes'
      }, {
        setUrl: function (url) {
          win.document.getElementById(field_name).value = url;
        }
      });
    }
  };

  tinymce.init(editor_config);
</script>

<script>
  {!! \File::get(base_path('vendor/barryvdh/laravel-elfinder/resources/assets/js/standalonepopup.js')) !!}
</script>
```

> **Note:** error refers to this line `tinymce.init(editor_config);`

`Blade`

```
{{Form::textarea('short_description', null, array('class' => 'form-control editor'))}}
```

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you server TinyMCE from your domain or from a CDN?

Comment: @Dmitry no from local, PS: is solved now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## SOLVED

I download again tinymce and reupload js files, now is loading without issue.